# show posts in different styling

Tags: theme-development, get-posts

I would like to show `categories` in the front page with different behavior:

- categories to show `posts` in two styles [Three `posts` having the same style and then another two with the same style]

[image: Three posts having the same style and then another two with the same style]

- another `categories` will show `posts` like below image

[image]

- for the `category` page itself, I would like to show the last three `posts` as featured with the same style, then the rest of posts having the same style.

This is my first wp `theme`, so how to make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I have developed a theme almost identical to yours.

This is how you can achieve this:

Basic idea is, create two different layouts: `layout-three.php` and `layout-two.php`
We will call them based on requirement. I have used an array to achieve this.

Below is the sample code for the template file (assuming you will show 5 posts per page and you already have your query and code structure ready):

```
$layout_call = array (
                    '1' => 'three',
                    '2' => 'three',
                    '3' => 'three',
                    '4' => 'two',
                    '5' => 'two'
);

$args = array (
    'cat' => 1, // <------edit with your desired category ID
    'posts_per_page' => 5
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    $counter = 1;
    get_template_part( 'layout', $layout_call[$counter] );
    $counter++;
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Now in your `layout-three.php`, write code for one small block out of three blocks of first part, and in `layout-two.php`, write code for one medium block of two blocks of second part.

That will do the trick.

Comment: Can I use this to show categories in the front page?

Comment: @Kareem yes sure. But you will need to set custom query for that.

Comment: @Kareem Check the updated code.

Answer (score -1):

from what i understand,you need to use custom codes for this. use this code to get the posts from a particular category.

```
<ul>
<?php


$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>

</ul>
```

edit the category id for the next loop.
thank you.